# How to mic a sleeping baby's breathing?

Tags: microphone, microphone-technique

I have a project for uni, I want to be able to detect if a baby has stopped breathing from one point in the house away from the baby. This would prevent cot death and could have lots of uses. Maybe in the future it could be used as a smart phone app.

So my questions are

What mic or device could be used to hear very quite sound at a long distance? over 3m

What are some easy ways to relay this information to a phone or just to let the user know the babe has stopped breathing.

Comment: Good luck.  As someone with a 2 month old myself, I can safely say the baby moves around too much and breathes too quietly (with too much background noise in the house) for something like this to be effective.  You could probably hear the breathing if the baby was stationary by using a super focused mic, but as soon as the baby moves, you won't be focused on the right spot anymore.  Background noises like fans, heaters, outside noise, etc will all drown out the sound of a baby breathing if you don't have it super focused.  If you do have any luck though, I'd be interested in what you do.

Comment: Lav mic taped to its face ;-) Sorry, not a father <apologetic grin>

Comment: Why do you need it to be over 3m?

Comment: A device to detect the baby's breathing already exists, but it uses a pulse oximetry, not sound. See the [Owlet](http://www.owletcare.com/), for example.